# button not displaying in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Edit re-wrote question:

Hi there I'm working on another student's project (taking over) there's no main storyboard, only a viewonctroller.Xib under resources a Viewcontroller.h and .m

I'm trying to add new buttons but they aren't displaying. I linked the new buttons to the viewcontroller.h and .m file with no actual code in the code such as

```
-(IBAction)button { empty }
```

in the .h file it's

```
   IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

The button's not displaying in the simulator however, Also the former student has every button in the app displayed in the same window and just uses the setHidden function to distinguish between menu's in game. I thought that maybe the button was just behind other buttons but when I go to editor-> send to front the option is grayed out.

```
  edit Sample code of ViewController.H 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
// Game Center -- ignore and or delete
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h> 
#import "GameCenterManager.h"
@interface SideWinderViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate,       /*ADBannerViewDelegate,*/ UIActionSheetDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate,
GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GameCenterManagerDelegate> {

// Game Center
GameCenterManager *gameCenterManager;
int64_t currentScore;
NSString* currentLeaderBoard;
IBOutlet UILabel *currentScoreLabel;
// End Game Center

IBOutlet UIImageView *ballpng;
IBOutlet UILabel *displaycredit2;
IBOutlet UILabel *displaycredits;
IBOutlet UIButton *easy;
IBOutlet UIButton *medium;
IBOutlet UIButton *hard;
IBOutlet UILabel *displayhighscore;
IBOutlet UILabel *Howtoplay;
IBOutlet UIButton *back;
IBOutlet UIButton *info;
IBOutlet UIButton *playbutton_mainmenu;
IBOutlet UIImageView *winder1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *socket1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *wheelcontrol2;
IBOutlet UILabel *seconds;
IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
IBOutlet UIButton *Restart;
IBOutlet UIButton *HIGHSCORE;
IBOutlet UIButton *pausebutton;
IBOutlet UIButton *resumebutton;
IBOutlet UIButton *gameStartButton;
IBOutlet UIImageView *mainmenu;
IBOutlet UIButton *credits;
IBOutlet UIButton *returnt
```

sample code for .m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SideWinderViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "Ball.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
// Game Center -- ignore and or delete
#import "AppSpecificValues.h"
#import "GameCenterManager.h"
// End Game Center
@implementation SideWinderViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[Restart setHidden:NO];
```

...

Comment: Is the correct ViewController class defined as the File Owner of the xib??

Comment: button is custom or default one?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Have you added any constraints?

Comment: I am not using auto layout I haven't added any constraints also other buttons from previous xcode 4 are being displayed and there seems to be no difference in the options

Comment: I even added [button setHidden:NO] still not displaying

Comment: have you sated any image to button? if yes than check that image is not transparent and its in the project bundle.

Comment: no images have been added, just default Text button in xcode 5

Comment: @RyanWilliams send sample code

Comment: are you using IOS 7 ?

Answer (score -1):

Thats enough to show a button
Check

1. Xib shown is the right one
2. Is tht button is covered by some other view added via code
3. Is the button property hidden checked or unchecked
4. Check button Frame

Comment: property is unchecked for hidden, I can't edit the z-index  with editor There's only one window

Comment: there's other buttons from when the project was in xcode 4 that display in the same xib/window and have same properties. I just can't seem to add new buttons

Comment: remove the outlet connection and see if the button appears in code